# Mozilla WebExtensions New guide

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, firefox, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-webextensions

In this link 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions

you can see that mozilla is now trying to make Chrome extensions for Firefox too with minimum changes.

If you go in this link
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/Porting_from_Google_Chrome

There is a guide about how to port from a chrome extension to firefox addon.

My problem is that there has to be an "addon id" in the manifest

and it has one example and i made my manifest like this.

```
    {
    "background": {
        "scripts": [
            "background.js"
        ]
    },

    "applications": {
    "gecko": {
    "id": "kwstasna13@gmail.com",
    "strict_min_version": "3.1.3",
    "strict_max_version": "50.*"

  }
},

    "browser_action": {
        "default_icon": "img/icon19.png",
        "default_title": "iFB PRO v3 The Ultimate Tool for Invites in Facebook",
        "default_popup": "popup.html"
    },
    "icons": {
        "19": "img/icon19.png",
        "38": "img/icon38.png",
        "48": "img/icon_48_2.png",
        "128": "img/icon_128.png"
    },
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "name": "iFB PRO for Facebook Invites Events&Pages",
    "description": " This is the ULTIMATE Invite Tool for Events and Pages in Facebook!! ",
    "permissions": [ "activeTab" ],
    "version": "3.1.3"
}
```

POPUP.HTML

```
<html lang="en">
    <head>

        <script src="popup.js"></script>
        <script src="jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="bootstrap.min.js"></script>


          <style type="text/css" media="screen">
            body { min-width:250px; min-height:700px; text-align: center; }
            #click-me-l { font-size: 20px; }
            #click-me-f { font-size: 20px; }
            .btnExample 
            {
                color: #FFFFFF;
                background: #5CADFF;
                font-weight: bold;
                border: 5px solid #ff;
            }

            .btnExample:hover 
            {
                color: #FFFFFF;
                background: #2E8AE6;
                cursor: pointer;
            }


            .btnExample1 
            {
                color: #FFFFFF;
                background: #5CADFF;
                font-weight: bold;
                border: 5px solid #ff;
            }

            .btnExample1:hover 
            {
                color: #FFFFFF;
                background: #2E8AE6;
                cursor: pointer;

            }
        </style>

    </head>
    <body>
        <body bgcolor="#3B5998">
        <img src="img/ifb-sketo.png">
        <font  color="white"><h1>Click here to invite friends to Pages</h1></font>
        <button id='click-me-l' class="btnExample">Pages</button>
        <font  color="white"><h1>Click here to invite friends to Events</h1></font>
        <button id='click-me-f' class="btnExample1">Events</button>
        <br><font  color="white"><h2>Please consider a donation in my PayPal account. Click the image below!</h2></font>
          <form action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post" target="_blank">
<input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_s-xclick">
<input type="hidden" name="encrypted" value="-----BEGIN PKCS7-----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-----END PKCS7-----
">
<input type="image" target="_blank" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/btn/btn_donateCC_LG.gif" border="0" name="submit" alt="PayPal - The safer, easier way to pay online!">
<img target="_blank" alt="" border="0" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/scr/pixel.gif" width="1" height="1">
</form>
<font  color="white"><h2>Click the image below to Like Us on Facebook</h2></font>
<a href="https://www.facebook.com/pages/IFB-Invite-all-to-Events-and-Pages/284580485083298" target="_blank"><img src="img/like.png">
    </body>
</html>
```

POPUP.JS

```
    function clickHandler1(e) {
        chrome.extension.sendMessage({directive: "popup-click-l"}, function(response) {
            this.close(); // close the popup when the background finishes processing request
        });
    }


 document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
        document.getElementById('click-me-l').addEventListener('click', clickHandler1);

    })


     function clickHandler2(e) {
        chrome.extension.sendMessage({directive: "popup-click-f"}, function(response) {
            this.close(); // close the popup when the background finishes processing request
        });
    }


document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
        document.getElementById('click-me-f').addEventListener('click', clickHandler2);

    })
```

BACKGROUND.JS

```
chrome.extension.onMessage.addListener(
    function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
        switch (request.directive) {

             case  "popup-click-l":
            // execute the content script
            chrome.tabs.executeScript(null, { // defaults to the current tab
                file: "pages.js", // script to inject into page and run in sandbox
                allFrames: true // This injects script into iframes in the page and doesn't work before 4.0.266.0.
            });
            sendResponse({}); // sending back empty response to sender
            break;
        case  "popup-click-f":
            // execute the content script
            chrome.tabs.executeScript(null, { // defaults to the current tab
                file: "events.js", // script to inject into page and run in sandbox
                allFrames: true // This injects script into iframes in the page and doesn't work before 4.0.266.0.
            });
            sendResponse({}); // sending back empty response to sender
            break;
        }
    }
);

chrome.runtime.onInstalled.addListener( function(details) {
  switch(details.reason) {
    case "install":

       chrome.tabs.create({url: "https://www.facebook.com/pages/IFB-Invite-all-to-Events-and-Pages/284580485083298?sk=app_128953167177144&ref=page_internal"});


      break;
    case "update":


      break;
  }
});
```

And then i have 2 js files with simple javascript code inside.

I install my extension perfectly in firefox nightly
it opens the popup.html
but when i push the buttons is not executing the javascript code.

Does anyone has any idea of why is not working?

As a chrome extension it works perfect.

Comment: Here's a nice artcile on step by step: https://hacks.mozilla.org/2015/09/lets_write_a_webextension/?utm_source=html5weekly&utm_medium=email

Answer (score 4):

There are some parts of the chrome extension API that have not yet been ported. Check the documentation for more info: https://wiki.mozilla.org/WebExtensions#List_of_supported_APIs

another page where the supported APIs are listed is here
<s>http://www.arewewebextensionsyet.com/</s>

Comment: can you link me the documentation of what has been imported please?

Comment: sorry i was mistaken about the message passing, they do support the chrome.runtime.sendmessage, its just "native messaging" that they dont yet  support,  bwintons link shows which apis are supported and which are not yet. thanks bwinton, i tried finding that link, but couldnt find it again.

Comment: So why my extension is not working? I don send native messages

Comment: the webextensions api is still in beta mode, they are working on it and fixing bugs in it, it should work ok when they release it officially. You can check the current list of bugs in the API here: http://www.arewewebextensionsyet.com/